# How to give limited access in visual studio 2015 Using Team foundation server 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

i want to give limited access or only selective page access other user in visual studio 2015 and using team foundation server 2013.
when user contact  team foundation server using visual studio other user only 
 selective pages access not full software page or code .

Comment: How is this a `C#` related question? Please make sure to use only relevant tags in your questions.

Comment: The access is not given in visual studio, but to the user.. so you can set the privileges you want to that user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as rmjoia said "the access is not given in visual studio, but to the user".

It will prompt to enter the user name and password when you first time to connect to TFS with visual studio.  So you just need to set the privileges you want to that user.

You can set the permission for specific user/group in **Security** or **Version control** tab, you can even limit access to the specific branch, iteration, area etc (eg : `switch to  Areas tab > Right click on an Area > Security`), just set that based on your requirements.

Please refer to this article for the permission settings: [Permissions and groups in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions)

---

**UPDATE:**

We can not create use account in TFS (can create TFS group), we can only add the existing user accrount to TFS.

You need to create user accounts in your domain (assuming you have the domain environment), or in your local machine which TFS server installed on it. Then add the created users to TFS.

Reference below screenshot (add local user for example).

[image]

[image]

Comment: How to Create Team Member Account Can you send me ScreenShort.

Comment: Ya awesome , Working great.